# Run ubuntu command sudo apt-get in linux Mandriva?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mandriva

How i can run the following command (for Ubuntu) in Mandriva 2005 ? What is the similar command ?

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 pyro mercurial build-essential bison flex mercurial python-numpy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

urpmi is probably your best bet for Mandriva 2005 (IIRC). So try this:

```
urpmi python-wxgtk2.8 pyro mercurial build-essential bison flex python-numpy
```

You might have to fiddle with the package names a bit, I'm not sure quite what they are in Mandriva 2005.

See [Mandriva urpmi docs](http://wiki.mandriva.com/en/Tools/urpmi) for more information.

Comment: i try to run this command, but: bash: urpmi: command not found

Comment: man urpmi is nornal run

Comment: You need to run it as root (or with sudo), were you?